# How to draw an image over a tabcontrol using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I have to draw image in a tabcontrol using C#. I got few hints to change DrawMode to OwnerDrawFixed, and SizeMode to Fixed. After that write handler for DrawItem event as:

```
this.tabControl1.DrawItem += 
    new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.OnDrawItem);

private void OnDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(tabPage1.Handle);/*e.Graphics;*/         

    DrawArrowImage(g);
}
```

Now this DrawImage() function start a timer which will keep redrawing an arrow image at next points to resemble the moving arrow. Now here I have few issues:

1. OnDrawItem is not being called as I run the application (alike OnPaint()). How can I do it?
2. As calling Invalidate() cause invoking paint event and the it calls OnPaint(), is there any way to invoke 'DrawItem' event so that inturn OnDrawItem() can be called?

thanks,
RPS

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong, the DrawItem event is only meant to custom draw the tab, not the tab page.  Simply implement the Paint event of the tab page.  Be sure to use the e.Graphics that is handed to you to do the drawing.

```
...
this.tabPage1.Paint += this.OnDrawPage;
...

private void OnDrawPage(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    DrawArrowImage(e.Graphics);
}
```

Comment: I have used Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(tabPage1.Handle); DrawArrowImage(e.Graphics);
its drawing but not as application starts. If I use Graphics g = e.Graphics; it draws immediately but behind Tab controls over the forms ...

Comment: Sounds to me like you subscribed the form's Paint event instead of the tab page's Paint event.

Comment: Thanks ... I got ur point, m doing the same now ... and able to draw images over tab page ... And to call paint handler repeatedly I m calling as : this.tabPage1.Invalidate(); .. but in this case other drawn images are flickering .. either in Paint handler I get the Graphics object as Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(tabPage1.Handle); or by Graphics g = e.Graphics; ... same flickering output in both ....  where in case of drawing over Window form, it was smooth.

Comment: In case of window form .. for smooth drawing, I was using double buffering:
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);

But why the same double buffering is not working in case of tab page ?